# Trying to Link a populated drop down list PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

As the title suggests I am trying to link a populated drop down list to a form on another page.

My dropdown list is currently connected to my database which displays the addressID's of 6 people. So when the user selects for example AddressID 3 it will take them to the next page (customerdetails.php) which will then allow them to update the form which will update the database accordingly.

My current code is as follows

```
<?php
//adding the database connection
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";

//connection to the databse
$dbhandle = mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die ("Unable to Connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL";

//selecting the database we want to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("my_guitar_shop2", $dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select my_guitar_shop2");
?>
<p>AddressID:</p>    <br>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT addressID FROM addresses";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='addressID' onchange = 'getAddressID(this)'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['addressID'] ."'>" . $row['addressID']   ."</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Now on the customerdetails.php page i have the code:

```
<?php
$adrresIDSelected = $_GET['addressID'];
?>
```

For the life of me I cannot seem to connect the 2 pages together.

Am i anywhere near the correct path? I would prefer not to use javascript as I have no prior knowledge of it.

Many thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
customerdetails.php page

```
<?php
 //adding the database connection
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $hostname = "localhost";

 //connection to the databse
 $dbhandle = mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die ("Unable to Connect to MySQL");
 echo "Connected to MySQL";

 //selecting the database we want to work with
 $selected = mysql_select_db("my_guitar_shop2", $dbhandle)
   or die("Could not select my_guitar_shop2");
 ?>

 <?php
   $addrresIDSelected = $_GET['addressID'];
 ?>
```

### Contact Form

```
<form class="form">

    <p class="first">
                    <label for="name">FirstLine</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstline" id="first"  />

    </p>

    <p class="second">
                    <label for="email">SecondLine</label>
        <input type="text" name="secondline" id="second"  />

    </p>

    <p class="city">
                    <label for="web">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="web"  />

    </p>        

    <p class="state">
                    <label for="web">State</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" id="web"  />

    </p>    

            <p class="zip">
                    <label for="web">Zip Code</label>
                    <input type="number" name="zip" id="web" />

    </p>    

    <p class="update">
        <input type="button" value="Update" />
    </p>
            <p class="remove">
        <input type="button" value="Remove" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: What does the Javascript function `getAddressID()` do?

Comment: Nothing it seems!! I am able to select my prefered addressID but once clicked it does not take me to the customerdetails.php page

Comment: Do you have that function implemented? If yes, post the source code of it.

Comment: <script>
    function getAddressID (option) {
        var addressID = option.value;
        
        window.location.replace ("<your_domain>/customerdetails.php?addressID =" + addressID);
    }
    
    
    
    </script>

Comment: This is the code. It now links to the next page but is giving me access forbidden error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution (no Javascript)**

For a solution without Javascript, you will need to use the `select` within a `form` element and use a submit button too to send the information completed/selected in the form to the desired page:

```
...
<form action="customerdetails.php" method="get">
<select name="addressID">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT addressID FROM addresses";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['addressID'] ."'>" . $row['addressID']   ."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Take me to the other page">
</form>
...
```

**UPDATE - Second solution (with Javascript)**

For using the `getAddressID` Javascript function to send the ID instead of using a form, you will need to update the function a bit:

```
<script>
function getAddressID (option) {
    var addressID = option.value;
    // you do not need the <your_domain> prefix here, as probably both your php scripts are on the same server/domain and same folder
    window.location.replace ("customerdetails.php?addressID =" + addressID);
    //-----------------------------------------------------^
    // Extra space must be removed!
}
</script>
```

Comment: And this method is still allowing me to be connected to the chosen addressID ive chosen? sorry i hope i make some sort of sense. Im all very new at this!!!

Comment: Just try both solutions and see what happens. The first one is the standard version of using forms in HTML. In the second solution you just do not need the <your_domain> prefix.

Comment: I tried both but i seem to like javascript more. the only issue it is giving me now is that on the customerdetails.php page i am recieving an  Undefined index: addressID error.

Comment: Please update your question with the full source code of customerdetails.php.

Comment: Please see the update in my answer (the Javascript function's body). There is an extra space before the `=` sign that needs to be removed.